# POST data and redirect to the same page CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I am using `'HttpSocket', 'Network/Http'` and am using 
`new HttpSocket()->post('uri','dataToBePassed)`

It does post the data but, I want user to be redirected to the page.
I tried passing `array('redirect'=>true)`, no go...

any ideas>

Comment: Why don't you use the `redirect` function ?

Comment: using $this->redirect will change the POST data, it will no more include POST data in it.

Comment: Why don't you store the POST data in a session, post it with your `HttpSocket` and then redirect the user to the destination page in which you would check for the session data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as this : We save data in Session and once I get call back, we put data from the Session variable!